# How to display dump data in IDA Debugger?

Tags: ida

Bit of a noob question, I'm working through some examples on crackmes.

In Ollydbg and x64dbg, in the stack, disassembler and registry windows, there are texts to show values of memory locations, for instance:

[image: Ollydbg descriptions]

I would have thought IDA would have had this information readily available in the debugger, however it seems the user has to hover over addresses to view it.

[image]

Is there a way to display this available in IDA? It is much more useful in Olly/x64 to have the text, rather than `debug070:7EFDE000` etc

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately there's not such option built into IDA, however you can write an [IDAPython](https://github.com/idapython) script for that, using some [UI](https://github.com/idapython/src/blob/master/examples/ex_uihook.py) and/or [DBG](https://github.com/idapython/src/blob/master/examples/debughook.py) hooks.

By hooking any time the debugger pauses and scanning register/stack addresses and adding comments (which will be visible).